# Different between “between” and “>= and <=" in mysql query?

Tags: php, mysql

What is the different between “between” and “>= and <=" in mysql query? There is any performance changes between both of them?

Answer (score 1):

The boundaries in `x > y AND x < z` are exclusive, whereas in `x BETWEEN y AND z` they're inclusive. So 5 is `BETWEEN 5 AND 6`, but it's not `> 5`. `BETWEEN` would be equivalent to using `>=` and `<=`.